# Post and Get actions async on facebook (Facebook .Net sdk)

Tags: .net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I have an app that posts to user wall after checking if it has permissions doing it.

Those actions are to calls to facebook graph api and may sometimes take few seconds if something went wrong.

I want to de-attach this actions from the other stuff i do that connected to my application and not facebook.

I thought of doing them in different thread but i heard there also an async way.

Can you help me decide which direction should i take?

Answer (score 0):

Go with Javascript SDK. Using Javascript SDK, it's asynchronous.

Comment: The system already writen in facebook c# sdk.
I want to make the current c# code work async when calls to facebook and sync when doing other things.